# Ignoring node_modules for compiling server-side ES6 with Webpack locally

Tags: node.js, webpack, server, ecmascript-6, raspberry-pi

I am working with a **Raspberry Pi Zero** that is my **server**, running my module.

Raspberry's are not the best to compile code so I want to **compile the server-side code locally**. To do so I need to compile the code without resolving my imports. Why that ?

Because the Server module **uses other modules that can only be installed on the Raspberry** (such as UPM or MRAA for sensors).

For now I compile on the Pi but it's slow.

So I'm trying to compile to ES6 locally with my config:

```
const path          = require("path");
const webpack       = require("webpack");
const nodeExternals = require("webpack-node-externals");

module.exports = {
    entry:
        {
            index: __dirname + "/src/index.js"
        },
    output: {
        // sourceMapFilename: "[name].map",
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "build"),
        filename: "[name].js",
        sourceMapFilename: "[name].map",
        chunkFilename: "[id].chunk.js"
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                include: [
                    path.resolve(__dirname, "src")
                ],
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
                use: {
                    loader: "babel-loader",
                    options: {
                        cacheDirectory: true,
                        presets: ["env"],
                        plugins: [
                            ["transform-runtime"],
                            ["transform-es2015-modules-commonjs-simple", { // Very important
                                "noMangle": true
                            }]
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({Hardlets: path.resolve(__dirname, "../Hardlets/build/index")}),
        new webpack.IgnorePlugin(new RegExp("/(node_modules)/"))
        // new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin(),
        // new HtmlWebpackPlugin({template: "./src/index.html"})
    ],
    target: "node",
    externals: [nodeExternals()],
    devtool: "source-map"
};
```

Which gives me an error because only the **devDependencies are installed locally but not the other dependencies** (sensors...):

> ERROR in ./src/hardlets/relays/Relays.js Module not found: Error:
>   Can't resolve 'jsupm_relay' in
>   '/home/stinky/Projects/gardener/Sensors/src/hardlets/relays'  @
>   ./src/hardlets/relays/Relays.js 1:1008-1030  @
>   ./src/HardletInstances.js  @ ./src/index.js
>
> ERROR in ./src/hardlets/dht22/DHT22.js Module not found: Error: Can't
>   resolve 'rpi-dht-sensor' in
>   '/home/stinky/Projects/gardener/Sensors/src/hardlets/dht22'  @
>   ./src/hardlets/dht22/DHT22.js 1:925-950  @ ./src/HardletInstances.js 
>   @ ./src/index.js

How can I **prevent webpack from trying to resolve/import** these dependencies ? The dependencies must be resolved at runtime.

There is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "gardener",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "watch": "webpack --watch",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "http://192.168.8.100:3000/pi/Gardener.git"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
    "babel-runtime": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs-simple": "^6.7.4",
    "webpack": "^3.8.1",
    "webpack-node-externals": "^1.6.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "upm": "^1.0.0",
    "rpio": "^0.9.19",
    "rpi-dht-sensor": "^0.1.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: Try appending those 2 dependencies on the externals array

Comment: I just tried @apokryfos, I doesn't work. I added
`externals: [
        nodeExternals(),
        {
            "jsupm_relay": "jsupm_relay",
            "rpi-dht-sensor": "rpi-dht-sensor"
        }
    ]`
Webpack compiles well but fails to load if I run it throwing:
**module.exports = rpi-dht-sensor;
                 ^
ReferenceError: rpi is not defined**

Comment: My assumption was that you don't need those exports to be compiled because they're already installed on Pi . If they're not then you have to actually install the dependencies locally as well. Just make sure you're running the compiled code on Pi and from a path where it can resolve the dependencies

Comment: `devDependencies are installed locally but not the other dependencies` ? For example, rpio supports mock mode on unsupported hardware, so you should be able to install it and compile just fine.

Comment: @apokryfos Yes you are right, all dependencies are installed on the Pi & only the devDependencies locally (to compile). Still the code does not run because webpack compiled with errors.
I can install all dependencies locally because I use packages like "upm" or "mraa" that are made to work for devBoards (Pi, Edison) only.

Comment: @GabrielBleu Yes, read the comment above. I can't mock this

Comment: Find all the compilation error points, generally webpack will replace a `require` with an error if it failed to resolve the dependency. However if you mark said dependency as external then webpack will not replace the requre at all which is Ok as long as you don't try to run the code locally and just deploy it.

Comment: @Pirix This option allows compiling MRAA/UPM on any system with npm and node-gyp. [from the doc](https://github.com/intel-iot-devkit/upm/blob/master/docs/installing.md#nodejs-bindings-only-npm)

Comment: @apokryfos it does compile without errors but then at launch it does not work because of the '-' in the name of the module.  module.exports = rpi-dht-sensor; ^ ReferenceError: rpi is not defined. Is it a bug from webpack ?

Comment: That line must come from somwhere. I doubt webpack put it there by itself. And that's indeed not really valid

Comment: @apokryfos For short, Webpack could not find the modules to exclude because they were not installed. I detailed my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The modules could not be excluded with `nodeExternals()` because it lists the modules in /node_modules/. However, the modules that are to be excluded are not installed locally so `nodeExternals()` does not do the job.

It needs to exclude them from by reading package.json.

This will read the modules from the package.json file & exclude them instead of the node_modules directory:

```
// webpack.config.js
var nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');
...
module.exports = {
    ...
    externals: [nodeExternals({
        modulesFromFile: true
    })], // in order to ignore all modules in package.json when bundling
    ...
};
```